Is Installing Hardie backer board on top of drywall safe for fireplace high ceiling?
We recently built home and hired outside contractor for fireplace large tiles 24*48 inches and Our ceiling height 19 ft .  we just realized after he built he used 1/4 inch of hardie backer board on top of dry wall directly using 2.5 inch screws . After that he used large format tile mortar to attach the tiles . Later we heard from other friends that backer board should not to be installed to dry wall , rather we need to break dry wall and screw backer board to the wood behind dry wall . We are very much worried , can you please clarify  installing Backer board onto dry wall is safe .

A picture of the situation would be helpful. I take it the tile in question is 19 ft up? When Hardie is used in close proximity of the heat source, closer than 36" from the fire box or more particularly a wood stove, the Hardie needs to be separated from the drywall by ceramic spacers to create an airspace between the drywall and Hardie. If the Hardie is 19 ft up in the air, it would hardly seem to be any issue at all.

Your tile is safe. The hardibacker can be attached on top of drywall.
The areas that it is not recommended to use the hardibacker over drywall or blueboard is in bathroom or areas that can be subject to moisture.

+1 And this is because of moisture issues causing mold between the sandwiched panels, not any structural or fire concerns.
